# Why is my navigation drawer empty?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am copying/pasting the example from [here](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android), however when I run it my drawer is completely empty. For example, in my Main Activity below after running `setAdapter` my listview is empty/null. Why is that?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private String[] mPlanetTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = "test";

    mPlanetTitles = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
    )
```

I've also changed all the `getActionBar` to `getSupportActionBar`.

Comment: This might sound stupid, but what is the background color of the listView and what is the color of the text of the list items ?

Comment: Not stupid, they're all set to default. I wouldn't worry about it if the DrawerList wasn't returning as "null"

Comment: Drawer layout is ok?

Comment: post more details, plz.